# Some certain regex don't match correctly when string is multi-line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I just started learning basic programming to solve a real-world problem. Currently I am struggling with some regex in Python, and hoping I could get a little bit of help here.

I need to telnet into a network switch, get its firmware versions before something else can be done. So, the output of command "show switch" is something looks like this: 
(Please note that depending on what particular firmware versions are actually running on Primary and Secondary, there may or may not be a line of "patchX-X" displayed.)

```
switch1.1 # show switch

SysName:          switch1
SysLocation:
SysContact:       support@extremenetworks.com, +1 888 257 3000
System MAC:       00:01:02:03:04:05
System Type:      X440

SysHealth check:  Enabled (Normal)
Recovery Mode:    All
System Watchdog:  Enabled

Current Time:     Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000
Timezone:         [Auto DST Disabled] GMT Offset: 0 minutes, name is UTC.
Boot Time:        Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000
Boot Count:       1
Next Reboot:      None scheduled
System UpTime:    0 minutes 0 seconds

Current State:    OPERATIONAL
Image Selected:   primary
Image Booted:     primary
Primary ver:      12.3.4.5
                  patch1-2
Secondary ver:    12.6.7.8
                  patch3-4

Config Selected:  primary.cfg
Config Booted:    primary.cfg
```

Following Python code is used to extract versions out of above output. 
Desired result will be  priVer=="12.3.4.5 patch1-2" and secVer=="12.6.7.8 patch3-4".

```
def updateReadout():
    global readout
    readout = tn.read_very_eager()

def checkFirmware():
    global priVer
    global secVer
    global priPatch
    global secPatch

    tn.write("show switch\n")

    updateReadout()

    priVer = re.findall(r"(?<=Primary ver:\s{6})\S+",readout)[0] 
    secVer = re.findall(r"(?<=Secondary ver:\s{4})\S+",readout)[0]

    try: 
        priPatch = re.findall(r"(?<=Primary ver:\s{6}\S{8}\s{19})\S+",readout)[0]
        priVer = priVer + " " + priPatch
    except IndexError: 
        print "Oops!IndexError!"
        pass

    try: 
        secPatch = re.findall(r"(?<=Secondary ver:\s{4}\S{8}\s{19})\S+",readout)[0]
        secVer = secVer + " " + secPatch
    except IndexError: 
        print "Oops!IndexError!"
        pass

    print "\n" + "Primary Version = " + priVer
    print "Secondary Version = " + secVer + "\n"
```

However, weird thing is, I could get "12.3.4.5" and "12.6.7.8" just fine, but IndexError constantly occurs when attempting to fetch those "patch" info next line, while Regex101 confirms that I do get a perfect match:
https://regex101.com/r/4ptQ05/1

Running the code gives me this:

```
Oops!IndexError!
Oops!IndexError!

Primary Version = 12.3.4.5
Secondary Version = 12.6.7.8
```

Then weirdly, copy&paste the result of "show switch" command and pass to variable "readout" manually does seem work fine with the same Regex:

```
import re

readout = """
SysName:          switch1
SysLocation:
SysContact:       support@extremenetworks.com, +1 888 257 3000
System MAC:       00:01:02:03:04:05
System Type:      X440

SysHealth check:  Enabled (Normal)
Recovery Mode:    All
System Watchdog:  Enabled

Current Time:     Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000
Timezone:         [Auto DST Disabled] GMT Offset: 0 minutes, name is UTC.
Boot Time:        Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000
Boot Count:       1
Next Reboot:      None scheduled
System UpTime:    0 minutes 0 seconds

Current State:    OPERATIONAL
Image Selected:   primary
Image Booted:     primary
Primary ver:      12.3.4.5
                  patch1-2
Secondary ver:    12.6.7.8
                  patch3-4

Config Selected:  primary.cfg
Config Booted:    primary.cfg
"""

def regexCheck():
    global priVer
    global secVer
    global priPatch
    global secPatch
    global readout

    priVer = re.findall(r"(?<=Primary ver:\s{6})\S+",readout)[0] 
    secVer = re.findall(r"(?<=Secondary ver:\s{4})\S+",readout)[0]

    try: 
        priPatch = re.findall(r"(?<=Primary ver:\s{6}\S{8}\s{19})\S+",readout)[0]
        priVer = priVer + " " + priPatch
    except IndexError: 
        print "Oops!IndexError!"
        pass

    try: 
        secPatch = re.findall(r"(?<=Secondary ver:\s{4}\S{8}\s{19})\S+",readout)[0]
        secVer = secVer + " " + secPatch
    except IndexError: 
        print "Oops!IndexError!"
        pass

def main():
  regexCheck()
  print "Primary Version = " + priVer
  print "Secondary Version = " + secVer

main()
```

Running above code returns:

```
Primary Version = 12.3.4.5 patch1-2
Secondary Version = 12.6.7.8 patch3-4
```

So I wonder if there's some kind of "multiline string formatting" issue going on here, but had no luck with searching or unfounded tryouts.

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated...

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Direct copy/paste all the lines from iTerm2 to either SublimeText or this text box on webpage may not preserve original format so I first `readout = readout.replace("\r\n", "@\r\n")` then `print readout`, it now looks like this:

```
switch1.1 # show switch@
@
SysName:          switch1@
SysLocation:      @
SysContact:       support@extremenetworks.com, +1 888 257 3000@
System MAC:       00:01:02:03:04:05@
System Type:      X440@
@
SysHealth check:  Enabled (Normal)@
Recovery Mode:    All@
System Watchdog:  Enabled@
@
Current Time:     Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000@
Timezone:         [Auto DST Disabled] GMT Offset: 0 minutes, name is UTC.@
Boot Time:        Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000@
Boot Count:       1@
Next Reboot:      None scheduled@
System UpTime:    0 minutes 0 seconds @
@
Current State:    OPERATIONAL             @
Image Selected:   primary                 @
Image Booted:     primary                 @
Primary ver:      12.3.4.5                @
                  patch1-2@
Secondary ver:    12.6.7.8    @
@
Config Selected:  primary.cfg                                          @
Config Booted:    primary.cfg                                          @
@
primary.cfg       Created by ExtremeXOS version 15.7.1.4@
                  123456 bytes saved on Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000@
switch1.2 #
```

Comment: Don't be so rigid with the number of spaces. You can use `+` instead.

Comment: If you're reading output directed at a terminal, it probably has CR-LF in it rather than just LF. In general this is the wrong way to go about doing this, though. See, e.g., G_M's answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for the suggestion, I did think about using + sign instead of number of spaces but then regex101 warns `+ A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {}
... prev_key = None
... for line in readout.splitlines():
...     try:
...         key, value = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
...     except ValueError:
...         current_line = line.strip()
...         if current_line:
...             d[prev_key] += ' {}'.format(current_line)
...     else:
...         d[key] = value.strip()
...         prev_key = key
... 
>>> import json; print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
{
  "SysName": "switch1",
  "SysLocation": "",
  "SysContact": "support@extremenetworks.com, +1 888 257 3000",
  "System MAC": "00:01:02:03:04:05",
  "System Type": "X440",
  "SysHealth check": "Enabled (Normal)",
  "Recovery Mode": "All",
  "System Watchdog": "Enabled",
  "Current Time": "Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000",
  "Timezone": "[Auto DST Disabled] GMT Offset: 0 minutes, name is UTC.",
  "Boot Time": "Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 2000",
  "Boot Count": "1",
  "Next Reboot": "None scheduled",
  "System UpTime": "0 minutes 0 seconds",
  "Current State": "OPERATIONAL",
  "Image Selected": "primary",
  "Image Booted": "primary",
  "Primary ver": "12.3.4.5 patch1-2",
  "Secondary ver": "12.6.7.8 patch3-4",
  "Config Selected": "primary.cfg",
  "Config Booted": "primary.cfg"
}
>>> d['Primary ver']
'12.3.4.5 patch1-2'
>>> d['Secondary ver']
'12.6.7.8 patch3-4'
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but it could be better if you explain what you are doing in a few words.

Comment: Wow thanks dude! This is much more complicated than an amateur like me who's frankensteining a simple script could easily understand...anyways this returns some errors like "KeyError: None" which is what `d[prev_key] += ' {}'.format(current_line)` gives me...maybe your code is Python3 while I'm running Python2.7...plus with nhahtdh's help I just figured there seems to be 16 more white spaces after "12.3.4.5" before it gets a "\r\n", so not sure if your solution will work it out

Comment: @Freddy This code uses your own `readout` string and provides your expected output (with no errors raised). If you are using some other `readout` string as input, you would need to provide that since I have nothing else to test this code with. Accounting for that `KeyError` would be a simple fix but it would just be guess work until you provide the actual input string which caused it.

Comment: @nhahtdh The code reads like plain english, I'm not sure what type of explanation you actually need. Read line by line, split into key/value pair. If you can't split into key/value pair, handle it by either skipping empty lines or adding the current `'patch'` line to the previous key's value.

Comment: @G_M Sorry for the ignorance about carriage return and line feed, I updated the original question to provide more info and hopefully useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: @G_M: Not much - just a line that describe your approach - that is parse the input and a note on how you handle text continuing on the next line. In your code, you are assuming `:` never appear in the value part of a continuing line so you attempt to split by `:` to detect a new key. If the assumption is not correct, your code will break.

Comment: @G_M Thanks for looking into this, your code works with my old carelessly copy-pasted `readout` string but doesn't seem to work with newer `readout` or real device.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm way too entry-level to understand this clearly too but G_M's code does a pretty good job on the `:` thing - values like mac address and date/time look great

Comment: @Freddy: If let's say a `:` appears in 2nd line of version number, then the code will fail. Probably will not happen here, but since we don't know all the possible output of your switch, there should be some sort of warning just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stems from a mismatch between how the script handles newlines vs how it is handled in your editor.

I ran your code, and replaced all "\n" with "\r\n" and got the same result that the script gets when it ran against the switch:

```
>>> main()
Primary Version = 12.3.4.5 patch1-2
Secondary Version = 12.6.7.8 patch3-4
>>> readout = readout.replace("\n", "\r\n")
>>> main()
Oops!IndexError!
Oops!IndexError!
Primary Version = 12.3.4.5
Secondary Version = 12.6.7.8
```

Please double-check that the telnet-session is not adding any additional carriage-returns that you are not expecting. Or changing the regular-expression to match this.

Comment: To check what telnet session has got, I used your method to replace \r\n with @ sign try to visualize it. If I did it right, there are actually 16 spaces behind "12.3.4.5", then a "\r\n", then 19 spaces before it hits "patch1-2"... Now question becomes "How can I correct `priPatch = re.findall(r"(?<=Primary ver:\s{6}.24)(*CRLF)(\s{19})\S+",readout)[0]` since this syntax is wrong" ...